Problem on Right Inverses of Matrices
Let $n,m$ be integers with $n \leq m$. Let $A, B$ be $n \times m$ real matrices of rank $n$ (i.e., of full rank).
I would like to show that there exists an $m \times n$ matrix $C$ such that:

$AC = 1_n$ i.e., $C$ is a right inverse of $A$,
$B C A = B$.

Moreover, is $C$ unique?
Thank you in advance for your help.
Edit: as shown in the answers, the problem has no solution in general. Can you give conditions on $A,B$ such that $C$ exists? More specifically, is the statement true for `generic' $A,B$ i.e., for almost all $A,B$?

In what ring are your matrices taking their entries ?

Any field, but I am mainly interested in real numbers.

Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad B= \begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $AC=1$, then necessarily $C= \begin{bmatrix}1\\ x\end{bmatrix}$ for some scalar $x$. But then
$$
BCA=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ x &0\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x&0\end{bmatrix}\ne B.
$$

Thank you! Can you give conditions on A and B such that this is true?

A sufficient condition is that $A$ and $B$ admit singular value decomposition with the same unitaries.
